# Tetrahedron from 5 edges with 3 equal lengths

Tags: geometry, polyhedra

Given are $5$ edge lengths $a,a,a,b,c$ of a tetrahedron. The three equal edges of length $a$ and the other edges $b,c,d$ are distributed as shown in the sketch. It is also given that $a\le b, a\le c, a\le d$. What is the length of the sixth edge $d$?

**Edit: In a previous version the wrong sketch was shown. Now the right figure is shown.**

[image]

Note:

It is simple if the figure would be planar, but it is a three-dimensional shape. Also the edges must be labelled as in the sketch else we would get a different tetrahedron.

Comment: There are, in general, infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I don't think the problem is well defined. In other words: given $a,b,c$ there are infinite possibilities for $d$. To see it, just bend/rotate the triangle with side lenghts $b,a,a$ around the $b$-segment axis and see that $d$ changes

Comment: I dont think that the tetraahedron (and therefore D) is uniule defined if only five sides are given.  The angle between c and a ,opposite to d,  can be arbitrary choosen

Comment: The question is underdetermined. So the comments that are given are enough.

Comment: Even the part that is given need not produce a tetrahedron.  Nothing in the givens requires $c \leq a+b$, so the upper-left "triangle" may fail to close.

Comment: The sketch was replaced by the right one. Does the comments hold?

Comment: Yes, they still hold. You can freely rotate triangle $aab$ about the upper-right $a$ edge, giving many different values for $d$.